# Using AND operators to search csv files

Tags: python-3.x, csv

i have made a small CVS file with one line of code to attempt to write an algorithm that will check if a inputted sequence of variables is in the same sequence in the same order (i am going to used this in a much larger code to search a 78 thousand line CVS file ) but the if statement i am running is encountering some problems as it only works with 3 or less AND operators and with anymore doesn't work and i cant understand why. i have run other if statement at the bottom of the page to prove that more than 3 AND operators does work so im stumped to why my prior statement doesn't so please help . i will send the code after this so please if you have any suggestions please tell me.

```
file = open("cars.csv","r")
car_make = ("audi")
car_model = ("a3")
car_year = ("2008")
car_colour = ("grey")
car_mileage = ("146")
car_price = ("1245")

found = "No"
 
for line in file:   
  details = line.split(",")
  make = details[0]
  model = details[1]
  year = details[2]
  colour = details[3]
  mileage = details[4]
  price = details[5].strip()


  #print(make, model)

  if (car_make.title() == make and car_model.title() == model and car_year.title() == year and car_colour.title() == colour  and car_mileage.title() == mileage and car_price.title() == price):
    
      print("Cars found: ")
      found = "Yes"
      print("[" + make + " " + model + " Release year:" + year + " Colour:" + colour + " Mileage:" + mileage + " Price:" + price+"]")
      print(details[0])
      print(details[5])
     
if found == "No":
        print("Sorry, your car was not found")
file.close()

a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
d = 1
e = 1
if(a==1 and b==1 and c==1 and ... and d==1 and e ==1):
  print(" WHY NOT WORK ON MY CODE")
else:
  print("whelp we gave it a try ")
```

and then ill now paste the data base its only one line but as i said its to test the code

`Audi,A3,2008,grey,146,1245`

i have tried everything from doing the first if statement with 3 AND operators which if is true will run another if statement with the other 3 AND operators,it didn't work . i have tried 3 AND operators and if true would run a function with the remaining 3 AND operators but yet again to no success . i am just trying to write an algorithm that will search through a CVS file for 1 line that has a list of numbers in the same sequence to sequence inputted so if you have any advise or other solutions please say .

Answer (score 0):

You compare `car_colour.title() == colour`. From the CSV you read `colour` as `grey` (starting with a lowercase character). With `title()` you convert `car_colour` from `grey` to `Grey` (starting with an uppercase character). So you compare `Grey` with `grey` which is `False`.

If you take `Audi,A3,2008,Grey,146,1245` as CSV-input, the row will be found.

Comment: thank you so so so so so so so much you are a legitimate life saver